# URL masking to completely different url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have 2 x domain names

https://www.example1.co.uk - This is my main site.
http://www.example2.co.uk

This is my regional sub website example1.co.uk/
I've presently got URL forwarding from www.example2.co.uk to the above URL, but as it was in a frame, the responsive nature of the sub site is crap!  I've now switched off the forwarding stealth (frame) and waiting for it to replicate.

Now for my question.  Is there a way of using the .htaccess file so that when I open example2.co.uk to open the / page that it can display the example2.co.uk URL and not the example1.co.uk one?

Thanks

Stephen

Comment: 1) why? 2) Are they on the same server? I'm skeptical because completely spoofing a URL as you are suggesting looks like a phishing attempt. This may also be an **[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/360627)**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about webmastering / DNS and is probably better suited to our sister site at Pro Webmasters: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes they are both on the same site GrumpyCrouton.  What's an XY Problem?  If it's off topic, what does that mean MrWhite?

Comment: Yes they are both on the same site GrumpyCrouton.  What's an XY Problem?  The reason for wanting to do this, is that the main site national survivors network is just that national,  I'm having difficulty locating funding to keep the site running.  Setting up a Liverpool subset of main site allows me to do regional funding applications. Which is why want it to  show different URL when showing /liverpool.  If it's off topic, what does that mean MrWhite? Apologies I'm new here.  Thanks.